# Thread safety and bit-field

Tags: c++, c, thread-safety, bit-fields

I know that bit-field are compiler dependant, but I haven't find documentation about thread safety on bit-field with the latest g++ and Visual C++ 2010.

Does the operations on a bit-field member are atomic ?

Comment: What do you mean by "thread safe"?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Are you back? I'm assuming that he is asking if the operations on a bitfield member are atomic.

Comment: I mean, different members can be accessed or assigned, by different thread without interference.
@the_drow: exactly, I will correct the question.

Comment: Then you're looking for *atomic* reads/writes to bit fields. If you want strict ordering of the reads/writes you need *synchronized* access to bit fields. It sounds like you may need both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Thread safe" is unfortunately a very *overloaded* term in programming.

If you mean **atomic** access to bit-fields, the answer is no (at least on all processors I'm aware of). You have **atomic** access to 32bit memory locations on 32bit machines, but that only means you'll read or write a whole 32 bit value. This does not mean another thread won't do the same thing. If you're looking to stop that you likely want synchronization.

If you mean **synchronized** access to bit-fields, the answer is also no, unless you wrap your access in a higher level synchronization primitive (which are often built on atomic operations).

In short, the compiler does not provide **atomic** or **synchronized** access to bit fields without extra work on your part.

Does that help?

**Edit**: [Dr. Dan Grossman has two nice lectures on atomicity and synchronization I found on UOregon's CS department page](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/summerschool/summer06/advanced.html).

Answer (score 5):

When writing to a bit-field, there may be a time window in which any attempt by another thread to access (read or write) any (same or different) bit-field in the same structure will result in Undefined Behavior, meaning anything can happen.  When reading a bit field, there may be a time window when any attempt by another thread to write any bit-field in the same structure will result in Undefined Behavior.

If you cannot practically use separate variables for the bit-fields in question, you may be able to store multiple bit-fields in an integer and update them atomically by creating a union between the bit-field structure and a 32-bit integer, and then using a CompareExchange sequence:

1. Read the value of the bitfield as an Int32.

   Convert it to a bitfield structure

   Update the structure

   Convert the structure back to an Int32.

   Use CompareExchange to overwrite the variable with the new value only if it still holds the value read in (1); if the value has changed, start over with step (1).

For this approach to work well, steps 2-4 must be fast.  The longer they take, the greater the likelihood that the CompareExchange in step 5 will fail, and thus the more times steps 2-4 will have to be re-executed before the CompareExchange succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update bitfields in thread-safe way you need to split your bit-fields into separate flags and use regular `int`s to store them. Accessing separate machine-words is thread-safe (although you need to consider optimizations and cache coherency on multiprocessor systems).

Comment: Do you mean that access to machine-words are atomic operations?

Answer (score 1):

See the Windows [Interlocked Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686360)

Also see this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039861/how-to-get-gcc-to-generate-bts-instruction-for-x86-64-from-standard-c)

Answer (score 0):

just simple use atomic.AddInt32
example:

```
atomic.AddInt32(&intval, 1 << 0)      //set the first bit
atomic.AddInt32(&intval, 1 << 1) //set the second bit
atomic.AddInt32(&intval, -(1 << 1 + 1 << 0)) //clear the first and second bit
```

the code is in Go, i think c++ also has some thing like atomic.AddInt32

Comment: Go isn't C++. For this to be a useful answer, you'd have to explain it in C++.

Comment: Adding won't work if the bit is already set. You'd have to test whether the bit is set first.