# How to write the btr instruction with 'asm volatile'

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, c++14

What is a correct implementation that uses btr to reset a bit in an integer in C++ with the extended assembly (`asm volatile`) syntax?  I need to return the value in the bit before the reset.

This is the implementation I have, is this correct for a 16 bit integer?

```
std::uint16_t reset(std::uint16_t& integer, std::uint32_t bit) {
  auto success = false;
  asm volatile("lock btrw %1, (%2); setnc %0"
               : "=r"(success)
               : "i"(bit), "r"(&integer)
               : "memory", "flags");
  return !success;
}
```

Is this implementation correct?  Have I missed any detail?  I am not very familiar with the `asm()` syntax or with x86 assembly.

Comment: Regarding the close vote, I do not believe I am asking why my code is misbehaving, but rather if I have missed any detail that might make this code behave badly in unforeseen circumstances.  StackOverflow is the only source I have for reliable information in this area.  The x86 docs don't translate well to the syntax here.

Comment: Purely as a matter of interest, what software product are you creating that requires these many (in your case) abstruse operations? And I haven't voted to close or downvote you here, I'm genuinely interested.

Comment: I'd personally recommend not using inline asm even for this. I believe compilers have intrinsics you can call to perform this operation. [MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/intrinsics/bittestandreset-bittestandreset64?view=vs-2017),

Comment: `"r"(&integer)` should probably be made into an output constraint. `"=m"(integer)` . that will also capture the fact that you are modifying the value at that address.You can then remove the parentheses around `%2` Your compiler should support the intrinsic for this already.

Comment: Instead of `"r" (&integer)` you should use `"m" (integer)`. Also it should be a read-write operand and you should drop the `memory` constraint. Also note that the `i` constraint is compile time so it will not work if the value is only known at runtime (but there is a `btr r/m16, r16` you could use). Finally, `success` is a misleading name (and has misleading type) and also you could just spare the negation if you used `setc`.

Comment: @Jester could you formalize that with full asm() blocks?  I don't think I am able to follow your answer without looking at the whole expansion you have in mind :(

Comment: @MichaelPetch same ^

Comment: @NeilButterworth At the moment, I'm just experimenting with different optimizations, and trying to see which instruction has the least overhead.

Comment: OK, what software product do you _intend_ to produce.

Comment: @NeilButterworth there is a synchronization library that uses `fetch_and()` instruction.  I am just experimenting with this to see if it has any effect

Comment: For what purpose? What is the point in programming if you don't produce something useful? I suppose you see programming something like a crossword puzzle?

Comment: BTR with a memory operand is very likely to be slower than either BTR with a register operand or the equivalent C code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039861/how-to-get-gcc-to-generate-bts-instruction-for-x86-64-from-standard-c#comment88671043_2392292

Comment: @NeilButterworth I am legitimately trying to optimize the synchronization library.  How do you assume that I am trying to do something that is not useful here?

Comment: Because you don't say what any of this, including this very vague library,  is going to be used for.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I mentioned it was for a synchronization library, I am afraid I can't tell more than that in a public forum at the moment :/

Comment: If it's for synchronization across threads in a multiple CPU environment then you left out LOCK prefix that would make it atomic.

Comment: @RossRidge only did so because I thought it was not relevant, I'll add it back.  My understanding was that adding the lock prefix would make it atomic and would impose acquire-release ordering automatically

Comment: The overhead is going to be dominated by the LOCK prefix, so your choice of instruction isn't going to matter. Though BTR could only make it worse as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version that replaces the `memory` clobber with a proper read-write operand instead of passing in the address in a register and also gets rid of the `setnc` (requires gcc 6+). Added `r` to cover the case where `bit` is not known at compilation time. Changed `success` to more readable `was_set` with `bool` type. Note if you want this to be atomic you also need to add a `lock` prefix. For compiler memory barrier you might need to put the `memory` constraint back.

```
bool reset(std::uint16_t& integer, std::uint32_t bit) {
  bool was_set;
  asm volatile("btrw %w2, %1"
               : "=@ccc"(was_set), "+mr"(integer)
               : "ri"(bit)
               : "cc");
  return was_set;
}
```

The atomic version could look like:

```
bool reset(std::uint16_t& integer, std::uint32_t bit) {
  bool was_set;
  asm volatile("lock btrw %w2, %1"
               : "=@ccc"(was_set), "+m"(integer)
               : "ri"(bit)
               : "cc", "memory");
  return was_set;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify what difference the memory constraint makes here?  I do intend to add a lock prefix to this.  I updated the question accordingly.  What ordering does `memory` impose (as defined by `std::memory_order`)?

Comment: Note that `lock` does not work with register operands so you might want to change the `+mr` to just `m` then. The `memory` constraint would force the compiler to flush and reload any other things that may be held in registers.

Comment: So the `memory` constraint is the same as `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)` (`MFENCE`)?

Comment: @Curious It's a compiler barrier. It has no effect on the the CPU reordering of memory accesses, just the compiler's reordering.

Comment: @Curious: The `lock` prefix makes it a full barrier for *runtime* memory reordering, like `mfence`.  So with that *and* a barrier against compile-time reordering, you have both effects of `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)`.  BTW, using inline asm for this probably has no advantage over pure C++ atomic `fetch_and`, which can compile to `lock btrw` given a single-bit mask.  (I think gcc and clang know that optimization).  C++20 `atomic_ref` will make it official that you can do atomic stuff on a normal variable, but until then I guess just cast.

Comment: This seems to return the opposite value?  When I do reset(0b0, 0) I get true, when I should be getting false.  Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: I don't think this is correct, it produces bad output for me.  I get `56` when I try `reset(0, 0);`  Could you update the answer with the correct version?

Comment: You get `56` for what? `reset(0, 0)` should not even compile. `reset(x, 0)` with `x=0` works for me (but with inline asm that doesn't say much) Also all other test cases I tried work.

Comment: @Jester yes i mean with an integer lvalue argument. I don't get the same value :( is there a platform with minimum compatibility here or something?

Comment: @Jester This seems to work on my platform but does not in godbolt https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MUs81E.  Any idea why?

Comment: `i` only works for compile time constants. You can use `ri` as I have.

Comment: @Jester Does it make a runtime difference when compiled btw?

Comment: @Jester Why does this not work either?  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/QKrYf2 prepending the `r` before the `i` because of compile time constants didn't seem to help in clang..

Comment: Because you used a 32 bit register. Cast `bit` to `uint64_t` or use `%q1`.